# Change column Row value of database automatically if condition is true

Tags: c#

Please i have a table in my access database with four column(Name,DOB,Age,Status). In my program i want the status row value to change automatically if the condition is true. if the age of a person is between 0-10 status column= "Baby",10-20 status column= "Youth",20-50 status column= "Adult" and 50-100 status column= "Old Age". To have the age automatically i use DateTime.today.year - DOB.year.[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qlVj.png)

```
enter code here  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        string query = " select * from StatBD ";
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        dataGridView1.Columns["N°"].Visible = true;
        con.Close();
    }
```

[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Du5R3.png)

Comment: Both `Age` and `Status` are derived values, and you should wonder if you want them in your database at all. If you use an ORM, or otherwise define a domain class, these two properties can easily be implemented as read-only in that class, incorporating your business logic. Alternatively, fill both columns with a before_read trigger. MS Access should have documentation on creating that.

Comment: I have marked this question as a duplicate. You should refer to that for a solution. Basically you need to handle the `CellFormatting` event of the DataGridView and set the text based on your logic. You should attempt a solution with that, if you get stuck with a specific problem while doing that then feel free to ask a new question about the problem, and include your attempted code up to that point